# What does $e^TAe$ equal?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that spectrum  of $G$ $spec(G)=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_n)$, and suppose that $\beta=\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis to the adjacency matrix $A=A(G)$ of graph $G$ with corresponding eigenvalue of $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_n$. Then there exists number $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n \in R$ such that $e=\{1,1,\ldots,1\}=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_ix_i$. However, I don't understand why $e^TAe=\sum^n_{i=0}\alpha^2_i\lambda_i$ follows from the fact that $\beta$ is an orthonormal basis, which is not obvious to me.

I haven't touched linear algebra for quite a bit of time, and the following is what I could come up with:
$e^TAe=e^T[A_1 | A_2 | \ldots | A_n]e=[e^TA_1 \; e^TA_2 \ldots e^TA_n]e$.
How can I get rid of $A_i$ terms to obtain $\sum^n_{i=0}\alpha^2_i\lambda_i$?

Comment: Just write out the equation: $e^TAe = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i x_i\right)^TA\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i x_i\right) = \sum_{i,j=1}^n \lambda_i \alpha_i\alpha_j x_ix_j = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i^2\lambda_i$ because $x_ix_j = 1$ when $i=j$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. Alas I was typing all this as an answer, while you were making your +1 comment. I'll not delete my answer but it doesn't deserve any credit.

Comment: @ancientmathematician someone has to write one, I was just too lazy to do it :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the expression of $e$ in terms of the orthonormal basis we have $e^TAe=(\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i x_i)^TA(\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_j x_j)$.

By the linearity this gives
$e^TAe=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_i \alpha_j x_i^TAx_j$.

As $x_i$ is a $\lambda_i$ eigenvector we get
$e^TAe=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_i \alpha_j \lambda_i x_i^Tx_j$.

As the $x_i$ are orthonormal we have
$e^TAe=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_i \alpha_j \lambda_i \delta_{ij}$, which simplifies to
$e^TAe=\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i^2 \lambda_i $.